# Rails_admin authentication works in development but not Heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, heroku, rails-admin

I recently added rails_admin to my app to modify its database without going into the backend.

In config > initializers > rails_admin.db I have:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with do
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Site Message') do |username, password|
      username == 'foo' && password == 'bar'
    end
  end

  config.main_app_name { ['app_name', 'Admin'] }

  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app
  end
end
```

When viewed in `localhost:3000/admin`, a window appears asking for the name and password I put into the app.

I'm being a little unorthodox not using CanCan, Devise, or the like but I don't think my small site would require that much work for authentication (I'm willing to work with those, though, if there is no other solution to this).

After deploying to Heroku, the `/admin` page still works, but completely bypasses the authentication step. I don't see why Heroku would be so picky. Is it not taking the `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic` method? Or is it that I missed a step in Heroku deployment (I just used `git push heroku master`)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, answering my own question in case anyone else runs into this issue.

This was actually an issue I was having with Git, not Heroku. The initializers (which contained my authorization code), were not being tracked with git. I simply needed to type "git add config/" into the command line to track the config files (including the initializers), commit changes, then upload to Heroku.